# streamWriter does not apply changes until I restart my game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, streamwriter

I'm making a game in Unity with an editor level that writes the level data in a .txt

My problem is that changes to the file are not applying correctly because I only can see them when I restart the game.

When the player creates a new level i use this:

```
TextAsset txtFile = Resources.Load<TextAsset>("Levels");
StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(new FileStream("Assets/Resources/" + levelsManager.filename + ".txt", FileMode.Truncate, FileAccess.Write));
```

And at the end of the method I close the StreamWriter.

```
    streamWriter.Flush();
    streamWriter.Close();
    streamWriter.Dispose();
```

Moreover if the user creates multiple levels, only the last one is saved.

Changing the filemode to apend does not work because after restarting the game and creating a level it also creates again the stored levels.

¿Is there a way of refreshing the document so I don't have to restart the game everytime I create a level?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: are you reading the file again ?

Comment: Are you reusing the same filename? You dont show that changing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to refresh the assets in Unity using [`AssetDatabase.Refresh`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.Refresh.html).

---

**However**

> When the player creates a new level i use this

Note that none of this will work in a built application!

After building your app the `Resources` are **read-only**. Anyway note from [Best practices -> Resources](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/assets-resources-and-assetbundles#5c7f8528edbc2a002053b5a7)

> **Don't use it!**

You probably rather would want to store the default file in [`StreamingAssets`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StreamingAssets.html) and use [`Application.streamingassetsPath`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-persistentDataPath.html) and then later in a build use [`Application.persistentDataPath`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-persistentDataPath.html) instead and fallback to `streamingAssetsPath` for reading only (again `StreamingAssets` is read-only after building)

For example like

```
public string ReadlevelsFile()
{
    try
    {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
        // In the editor always use "Assets/StreamingAssets"
        var filePath = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "Levels.txt");
#else
        // In a built application use the persistet data
        var filePath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "Levels.txt");
        
        // but for reading use the streaming assets on as fallback
        if (!File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            filePath = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "Levels.txt");
        }
#endif
        return File.ReadAllText(filePath);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.LogException(e);
        return "";
    }
}

public void WriteLevelsFile(string content)
{
    try
    {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
        // in the editor always use "Assets/StreamingAssets"
        var filePath = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "Levels.txt");
        // mke sure to create that directory if not exists yet
        if(!Directory.Exists(Application.streamingAssetsPath))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(Application.streamingAssetsPath);
        }
#else
        // in a built application always use the persistent data for writing
        var filePath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "Levels.txt");
#endif
        
        File.WriteAllText(filePath, content);

#if UNITY_EDITOR
        // in Unity need to refresh the data base
        UnityEditor.AssetDatabase.Refresh();
#endif
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Debug.LogException(e);
    }
}
```